# How To Prevent x.0 to become x when Typecasting Number to String in PHP

Tags: php

```
for ( $d = 1.0 ; $d < 10000; $d = $d + 0.1 ) {
  $file = "...(LCCallNum:({$d}))";
  var_dump($file);
}
```

I need $d to stay as 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0. But it keeps on being 1,2,3,4 when I variable interpolate, and dump $file. How do I prevent it from becoming an integer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `number_format` to fix this

```
<?php
    for ( $d = 1.0 ; $d < 2; $d += 0.1 ) {
      echo number_format($d,1)."\n";
    }
?>
```

live demo : https://eval.in/791122

Answer (score 2):

Use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) as follows:

```
for ($d = 1.0 ; $d < 10000; $d = $d + 0.1) {
    $file = sprintf("...(LCCallNum:(%.1F))", $d); 
    var_dump($file);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
string(20) "...(LCCallNum:(1.0))"
string(20) "...(LCCallNum:(1.1))"
string(20) "...(LCCallNum:(1.2))"
string(20) "...(LCCallNum:(1.3))"
string(20) "...(LCCallNum:(1.4))"
...
```